# Upgrade org-mode through Elpa

Tags: org-mode

I have some problems with another package and think it's because of an old org-mode.

org-version gives me:

```
Org-mode version 8.2.5h (release_8.2.5h-687-g9d39aa @ /home/b0ef/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.3.6/)
```

Not sure what this means. I'm running `org-8.2.5h`, but from an `org-9.3.6` directory?

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian
```

Comment: I would delete that directory, restart emacs, and go through the package installation again.

Comment: @NickD thanks, upgraded now;)

Comment: I can't mark your comment as a solution, right?

Comment: ask @NickD to write an answer to accept it as response, or do it yourself. Comments cannot be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

delete that directory, restart emacs, and go through the package installation again
Thanks NickD